# How to increase size in numpy so that the repetitions are local?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `a = [[1, 2], [3,4]]`. I want it to become array `b = [[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4, 4]`. Basicaly tile the array per element, not per array.

What I found is `numpy.tile` and `numpy.resize` but both of them copies the whole array, and tiling is done "globally". Is there any method in numpy, that would tile the data per element? I need a method from numpy because of performance reasons.

Comment: `np.repeat(a, 2, 1).repeat(2, 0)`, IIUC

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you! Mind adding it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I would say so. My question was just to find the right function/method, repeat was just was not a word I thought about. Can we somehow link that question and mark this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
# Creates 2 of each row
b = np.repeat(a, 2, axis=0)

# Concatenates b to itself so you have 2 of each element in each row
b = np.concatenate((b, b), axis=1)

# Sort the values (assumes that rows in original array were also sorted)
b = np.sort(b, axis=1)

# If original array does not have sorted rows, do below instead of np.sort to reorder columns properly:
num_cols = b.shape[1]
idx_1 = list(np.arange(0, num_cols-1, 2))
idx_2 = list(np.arange(1, num_cols, 2))
b = b[:, idx_1 + idx_2]
```